# How can I initialize an equation in matlab that has an arbitrary number of variables?

Tags: matlab

For example f(x) = x1.^2+.....xn.^2. The function takes an input n for how many different variables are in the equation. I then need to be able to use this equation to find a local minimum on some interval using newtons method.

Comment: How is this equation represented? Please show some code, it will help disambiguate the question.

Answer (score 5):

In the specific case of your example, I would just use an array

```
f = @(x) sum( x.^2 );

x1 = [1 2 3];   % f(x1) = 14
x2 = [1 2 3 4]; % f(x2) = 30
```

If you want something generic for unknown number of inputs then you need `varargin`.

When used as the nth input in a function definition, `varargin` is a cell array of all inputs from `n` to as many as are given. So if `varargin` is the only input in the definition, it stores all inputs when the function is called.

A verbose example (which would be saved in its own file `f.m` or a local function within your script) with looping over the inputs:

```
function out = f( varargin )
    out = 0;
    for ii = 1:numel( varargin )
        out = out + varargin{ii}^2;
    end
end
```

The anonymous function version with some more concise syntax would look something like this:

```
f = @(varargin) sum( [varargin{:}].^2 );

f(1, 2, 3)    % = 14
f(1, 2, 3, 4) % = 30
```